# Laravel - app.jss and CSS files versionning

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, versioning

I am trying to add files versions so that I don't need to force refresh with ctrl F5 at each change.

Here is how everything is added:

in template.blade.php

```
<script src="../js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/composants.css">
```

webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

Here is what I tried

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js'), 'public/css');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}


 <script src="{{ mix('../js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

But I get this error

**Unable to locate Mix file: /../js/app.js. (View: C:\laragon\www\projet\resources\views\template.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\projet\resources\views\template.blade.php)**

Thanks a lot for your help, I am a bit lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `mix()` then you have to provide relative path to `pubilc`.
So use `mix('js/app.js')`.
More details here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-mix